# Expected singleton: sezonekip() error pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo

This is my code and i get a singleton error. I am trying to build a football database and in this function I try to update teams position based on the result of a match.

```py
    @api.multi
    @api.depends('gola_home', 'gola_away')
    def perditeso_piket(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.gola_home > record.gola_away:
                self.sezonekip_home_id.fitore += 1
                self.sezonekip_away_id.humbje += 1
            elif record.gola_home == record.gola_away:
                self.sezonekip_home_id.barazime += 1
                self.sezonekip_away_id.barazime+=1
            else:
                self.sezonekip_home_id.humbje += 1
                self.sezonekip_away_id.fitore+=1
```

Comment: Expected singleton means : you are using recordset instead of record because self contains multiple recordset ..

Comment: for record in self: .... record here contain recordset so try to use record instead of self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using/programming it halfway correct. Looping on `self` is the safe way because it could be a multi record recordset. But you missed to use `record` later on in your incrementations.

Those incrementations are nothing more then setting a new value to the fields. But if `self` is a multi record recordset (not a single record recordset, which is called singleton) Odoo isn't allowing a direct write/update. So just replace `self` with `record` in your incrementations:

```py
    @api.depends('gola_home', 'gola_away')
    def perditeso_piket(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.gola_home > record.gola_away:
                record.sezonekip_home_id.fitore += 1
                record.sezonekip_away_id.humbje += 1
            elif record.gola_home == record.gola_away:
                record.sezonekip_home_id.barazime += 1
                record.sezonekip_away_id.barazime+=1
            else:
                record.sezonekip_home_id.humbje += 1
                record.sezonekip_away_id.fitore+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A mistake that often happens.
When you want to change a record it cycles to self, like you did, but all other fields must also be on record
example

```py
def method(self):
    for record in self:
        record.first_name = "Mark"
        record.last_name = "White"
```

This allows editing of that specific record. For example, the current registry